# OpenCV : How to clear Image Background of ID Card without losing quality

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, image-processing

I want to clear an image background of ID without losing quality, Keep only the text with white background

Using the following code is not efficient, produce high noise and distortion

```
 img = cv2.imread(imge)

# Convert into grayscale
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# Convert BGR to HSV
hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

# define range of black color in HSV
lower_val = np.array([0,0,0])
upper_val = np.array([179,255,135])

# Threshold the HSV image to get only black colors
mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower_val, upper_val)

# invert mask to get black symbols on white background
mask_inv1 = cv2.bitwise_not(mask)

mask_inv = cv2.blur(mask_inv1,(5,5))
```

How I can achieve clean background with these images

### Samples

[image]

[image]

### Output

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Using [Rembg](https://github.com/danielgatis/rembg) to get perfect output like below

[Rembg](https://github.com/danielgatis/rembg) is an offline tool to remove images background. you can simply install Rembg package using pip in python

```
pip install rembg
```

afterthat,

```
rembg i path/to/input.png path/to/output.png
```

[image: output1]

[image: output2]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).